# How to tell if the user already rated my UWP app?

Tags: c++, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Windows 10 Store UWP apps can use [`StoreContext.RequestRateAndReviewAppAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext.requestrateandreviewappasync) function, or simply a URL like this `ms-windows-store://review/?ProductId=9WZDNCRFHVJL`, to display a user rating window for the app:

[image]

I prefer the URL method since I can simply invoke it via [`ShellExecute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea) method.

But my question is how do I find out if the user had already rated my app, so that I don't display that rating window again?

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately not possible, but there is probably a good reason for it - if developers were able to check this programmatically, they could "cheat the system" by giving users who rated some bonuses/perks for reviewing the app.

Comment: Unfortunately that is the case, and it is the same with any other mobile platform as far as I am aware. You can store the flag locally, but it will not work across devices. Roaming settings can do that for you, but they are apparently being removed in a future release.

Comment: Really? They are doing away with roaming profiles? Is that what you mean, or am I confusing terms?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no such api can directly tell if the user already rated the UWP app, but you could use roaming data in your app which keeps your app's app data in sync across multiple devices.

If the user has rated your app, you can set "Yes" in the RoamingSettings, if the value from RoamingSettings is "No", you can display that rating window again. You could determine whether the rating is successful, e.g. in `StoreContext.RequestRateAndReviewAppAsync` method, the [ExtendedJsonData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storerateandreviewresult.extendedjsondata) property of the StoreRateAndReviewResult class contains a JSON-formatted string that indicates whether the rating request was successful. By ExtendedJsonData property, you can know if the rating is successful and then set the value to "Yes" in the RoamingSettings.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationDataContainer RatingSettings = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;
    //initialization
    if (RatingSettings.Values["isRated"] == null)
    {
        RatingSettings.Values["isRated"] = "No";
    }
    var isRatedStr = RatingSettings.Values["isRated"].ToString();

    if (isRatedStr == "No")
    {
        //display the rate windows
        if (//if rated successfully)
        {
            RatingSettings.Values["isRated"] = "Yes";
        }

    }
}
```

Or you can use the Get app ratings and Get app reviews methods in the Store analytics API to programmatically retrieve the ratings and reviews from your customers in JSON format. For more details, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/monetize/request-ratings-and-reviews#analyze-your-ratings-and-reviews-data).

Comment: Yes, but the user can install the app on an entirely different device not covered by roaming profile using their Microsoft account. And then what? It's so silly when MSFT tries to hide it from developers. Because the functionality is there. The Store App knows and uses it. So what stops me from reverse engineering it and calling that same API end-point that they keep secret? Just makes no sense. More security-by-obscurity BS.

Comment: The rating is not a type that needs to be restricted, users are allowed to rate multiple times. If you want to limit reviews, the function needs to be implemented manually. If the use does not open roaming data, you can only consider storing the data locally.

Comment: And if you want to get this feature, you can go to Feedback Hub(Start menu-> Feedback Hub) to submit your feature request.

Comment: Unfortunately Roaming settings are apparently going away :-( ... But note that other platforms have the same exact problem - you cannot tell whether the user already rated or not.

Comment: Where did you see that roaming settings are canceled?